stock management - determine opened state automatically
I have a database for animal rescues which has a medication section. I'd like to have the stock automatically deduct when it is used. The challenge is the opened bottles. For something like an antibiotic that has a shelf life of 7 days I'd need this to count down from first use until the bottle is completed then reset on next use OR alert when the 7 days has completed so that it can be disposed off.
Table Medication
Stores the medication names.



Medication ID
Medication
Class




1
Ciprofloxacin
Antibiotic


2
metacam
Anti-inflammatory



Table Meds Given
Records the details of the medications given to the animal. Will probably have to link this by profile_id to the meds profile table. Dose given is usually recorded in mg and would need calculating from the rescue meds profile table. E.g. 50mg would be about 3.3ml volume deduction.



given_id
medication_id
patient_id
Dose (mg)
given on




1
1
4
50
20/1/2024


2
1
4
50
13/5/2024



Proposed table Rescue meds profile
Stores some set medication profiles for the rescue as each medication can be formulated differently, e.g. 15mg/ml or 30mg/ml of the same medication. Column volume would be total volume. This dose would be the one used for the calculation above (50 (given) / 15 (profile)) = 3.3ml.



profile_id
medication
dose (mg)
volume (ml)
Exp (days)




1
1
15
125
5


2
1
30
125
365



Proposed table Stock adjustments
Tracks non-given stock adjustments, e.g. destructions and stock in. Following the example, at this point there were 4 bottles added in and 1 taken out of Ciprofloxacin 15mg/ml.



adj_id
profile_id
in/out
Volume (ml)




1
1
IN
500


2
1
OUT
125



Proposed table Inventory
Tracks the balance of the stock, so medications given and stock adjustments would both write to this table to update the balance. There should only be 1 record per profile_id in this table.



balance_id
profile_id
volume total




1
1
350


2
2
210



When a medication is given the form writes to two tables, one to record the transaction (meds_given) and one to deduct the volume (inventory). I can figure out the math to make the deductions and update the inventory.
What is a mechanism for it to know when a new bottle is opened and to alert users when the exp (in days is due)?
My first thought was to add a field opened_on to the inventory table to act as a trigger for future queries. Though I can't think how it would only be updated under certain conditions: e.g. whole bottle amounts such as every 125(ml).
If a medication is recorded as given and the balance is a whole amount e.g. 1000ml (4x 250ml bottles) then at a balance of 9992.5 ml (because 7.5ml was given) the date countdown begins. If at 6 or 7 days and the balance is between 750 and 1000 it triggers an alert to say it is expiring (the same would be true of 1-250, 250-500 etc.
If I did add a date field, it would need to remain in place and not be updated when other medications are given until the next 750/500/250 volumes are reached.

If you need to track when individual meds were opened, then your inventory needs to track each bottle of medicine separately, not just in total.

I would combine your medication and medication profiles into one table. That makes sense, because it simplifies your schema and why just having the names in a different table? So, I would have one big medication table containing all the information about all the different medications, that is types of bottles, there are. Something like:
Medication table:



ID
Name
Class
Concentration (mg/ml)
Volume (ml)
Expires (days)




1
Ciprofloxacin
Antibiotic
15
125
5


2
metacam
Anti-inflammatory
30
125
365



Next we need to keep track of what comes in stock, is opened, used or removed:
Bottles table:



ID
Medication
Arrived (date)
Opened (date)
Expiration (date)
Removed (date)
Used (ml)




1
2
2024-10-22
2024-10-25
2025-10-25
0000-00-00
56


2
1
2023-11-24
2024-02-11
2024-02-16
2024-03-05
125



So each bottle will be tracked individually. I would advice to use a bar code sticker on the bottle, applied when the bottle is put into stock and which can be scanned every time the bottle is handled. The bar code is directly linked to the ID in this table.
As you can see I have an 'Used' column in the bottles table, this is to track how much content the bottle probably has been used.
I also use an expiration date, to quickly check whether a bottle, that is about to be handled, can still be used. It is computed the moment the bottle is opened.
Finally we need to keep track of usage:
Usage table



ID
Bottle ID
Patient ID
given on
Dose (mg)
Volume (ml)




1
2
4
2024-01-11
50
7.5


2
1
4
2024-05-13
50
3.5



This is probably all that is needed. The bottles take up a central place in the schema, and each bottle is tracked in detail. The balance of all the bottles can easily be found in the bottles table, so no extra table for that is needed.
This schema can be expanded to account for pill, and other types of medication, as well.

Thank you, that's given me food for thought. The structure is this way as not only does it have the names of medication (to feed selects) it also has some info (contraindications etc) about each medication so was thinking to keep it to 1 record per medication. The profile is user editable so that the user can create a collection of medications and the strengths they use (as it may be 3 or 4) for use in their rescue.

I was also looking for it to be automatic is some way and not require any manual input of open bottles (additional user clicks). The people using it will want to keep things simple as possible. It also will be used for tablet based medication (just to add a spanner in the works)

@DanLindley Yes, there can be many reasons to split tables, but you would try to start with a basic design that works and only then think about splitting some tables. I think tracking bottles is a good idea. The world is imperfect. For instance, the database might register 20x 3.5 ml, leaving 55 ml in a 125 ml bottle, but in practice there will be more or less than that amount in the bottle. People might open 2 bottles of the same medication, for some reason. Tracking what happens with bottles means you cannot get out of sync with reality.

is there any way then, if I were to add each stock item individually I could create a form with a QTY which basically adds that qty to the table. E.g. Putting 5 in would create 5 of the same rows into the table ?

Yes, of course. There are two ways: 1. You can use a single MySQL INSERT query to insert the same row five times. This requires you to build the correct query string in PHP. 2. Use a loop in PHP to execute the same INSERT query for a single row five times. This might be slightly simpler than the first solution.

How would you build that to a user input? Eg a value in a field?

There's not enough room in a comment to show that, but I can give you some high quality links to lots of information about PHP/MySQL: PHP Delusions, PHP the right way, and security lessons. Save them, they can be very useful. There are also a lot of tutorial sites, but they aren't always of the best quality. I never need them, so I cannot advice on those.
